# Random string function does not always return same length

Tags: sql, postgresql

The intention of the following function is that it should return a random string 7 characters long containing the characters a and|or b and|or c:

```
create or replace function random_short() returns text as $$
    select array_to_string(
        array (
            select substring(
                'abc'
                from (random() * 3)::int for 1
            )

            from generate_series(1, 7)
        ),
        ''
    )
$$ language sql;
```

The problem is that sometimes it returns strings shorter than 7. I've played around with the values of various integers in the function (changing 3 to 4, for example) but can't figure it out. Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the expression with random returns `0`.  You can try this form instead:

```
select string_agg(substring('abc' from greatest((random() * 3)::int, 1) for 1), '')
from generate_series(1, 7)
```